# how to display dictionary on QDialog using pickle?

Tags: python, dictionary, pickle

As I am learning python ,i am having problem in displaying the dictionary. My dictionary gets save and retrieve but doesn't show on Qdialog.
I have attached my codes below. Please sort out me with this problem.

```
def button_click(self):
    aa = {}
    aa["Name"] = str(self.lineEdit_name.text())
    aa["Address"] = str(self.lineEdit_address.text())

    return aa
    print aa

def retrieve(self):
    aa = self.use_file()
    if (aa != None):      
        self.lineEdit_name.setText(aa[self.lineEdit_name.text()])
        self.lineEdit_address.setText(aa["Address"])

    return aa

def save_file(self, parent=None):
    bbb = self.button_click()
    filename = QtGui.QFileDialog.getSaveFileName(parent, 'Save File', '/home/reshma/untitled.txt', filter= '*.txt')
    fileobj = open(filename,"w")
    pickle.dump(bbb, fileobj)
    #fileobj.close()

    print bbb

def use_file(self, parent=None):
    bbb = self.button_click()
    filename = QtGui.QFileDialog.getOpenFileName(parent, 'Open File', '/home/reshma/untitled.txt', filter= '*.txt')

    if os.path.isfile(filename):
        file = open(filename, "r+")
        infile= pickle.load(file)
        print infile
        return infile
    else:
        return None
```

Comment: `aa` not global (so mean `self.aa = {}`)!

Comment: Sorry sir, can you explain in more detail. I didnt get.

Comment: replace all `aa` to `self.aa`.  why used a class if haven't any `self` objects ? Store to temp and call temp value(of course `blank` or `none`)